# Angular 14 - Not able to send values in props - Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular14

I am new to Angular. When I try to send props from parent component to the child component. I am getting the below error. My angular version is `14.2.5`.

> core.mjs:7635 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
> InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element':
> '[currentName]?' is not a valid attribute name. Error: Failed to
> execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[currentName]?' is not a valid
> attribute name.

[image]

Parent component:

```
<div class="content-box">
  <h2>Edit Listing</h2>
  <div>
    <app-listing-data-form
      [currentName]?="listing?.name"
      [currentDescription]?="listing?.description"
      [currentPrice]?="listing?.price"
      buttonText="Save Changes"
      (onSubmit)="onSubmit()"
    >
    </app-listing-data-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Child Component TS file :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Listing } from '../types';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-listing-data-form',
  templateUrl: './listing-data-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listing-data-form.component.css'],
})
export class ListingDataFormComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string = '';
  description: string = '';
  price: string = '';

  @Input() buttonText;
  @Input() currentName = '';
  @Input() currentDescription = '';
  @Input() currentPrice = '';

  @Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter<Listing>();
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Check here');
    this.name = this.currentName;
    this.description = this.currentDescription;
    this.price = this.currentPrice;
  }

  onButtonClicked(): void {
    this.onSubmit.emit({
      id: '0',
      name: this.name,
      description: this.description,
      price: Number(this.price),
    });
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-listings');
  }
}
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please remove the ? from [currentName]?, [currentDescription]?, [currentPrice]?

Comment: @cfprabhu Tried... It's not working..

Comment: What do you mean "not working" you need to provide more context. Removing the "?" should fix your issues. If there's another error provide the context of it. We can't help you if you say "it doesn't work" be more specific.

Comment: Getting `Error: src/app/edit-listing-page/edit-listing-page.component.html:7:8 - error TS2322: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.       
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

7       [currentPrice]="listing?.price"` error If I remove `?`

Comment: @penleychan The error message is available in the question itself. Kindly check.

Comment: That's because your `@Input` for currentPrice is expecting a string but you provided a value that is a type of `number | undefined` (listing.price).  Don't initialize it an empty string `= ''` give it a proper type.

Comment: Done... But now I am getting `error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

5       [currentName]="listing?.name"`. The currentName is in `string` only but still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comment you need to remove the `?` from `[currentName]?`, `[currentDescription]?` and `[currentPrice]?`

second, you don't need

```js
name: string = '';
description: string = '';
price: string = '';
```

you can just use `currentName`, `currentDescription` and `currentPrice`

third, looks like `listing?.price` is a number so define `currentPrice` as a number or convert it to a string

if you have problems with types you should check what you are providing and what is expected and then fix it accordingly.
as a quick solution (bad practice) you can also add `as string` and your problem will be fixed

Comment: If I remove `?`, Then I am getting `error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.       
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

5       [currentName]="listing?.name"` error.

Comment: But when I do `[currentName]?="listing?.name`. I am able to avoid that error message...

Comment: have you removed the unnecessary variables?
have tried with `as string` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried...

Comment: this is very wired because this tells typescript that the variable ist a string and not `undefinded`
there must be another problem in your code. You have to share the full code possibly on stackblitz

Comment: Okay... I will share it ASAP...